Newlines on parentheses and bitwise operations
I pulled this code for assembling sensor data from a datasheet. Is there any way to make this more readable, preferably by breaking up certain parentheses and bitwise operations into new lines and not messing with column widths?
var1 = ((((adc_T>>3) – ((BME280_S32_t)dig_T1<<1))) * ((BME280_S32_t)dig_T2)) >> 11;
var2 = (((((adc_T>>4) – ((BME280_S32_t)dig_T1)) * ((adc_T>>4) – ((BME280_S32_t)dig_T1))) >> 12) *
       ((BME280_S32_t)dig_T3)) >> 14;
t_fine = var1 + var2;
T = (t_fine * 5 + 128) >> 8;


One help might be to cast dig_T1 etc into local variables of the right type, and declutter the expressions. Let the compiler optimise it. As they did in t_fine = var1 + var2; and the next line, instead of a single expression.

Since C is a format free language, you can insert line breaks, spaces, indentation and other whitespace between language tokens as you like. It will not change the code. (The C preprocessor is an exception, but I tend to look at it as a separate tool and its syntax as not being part of the C language. However, it is specified in the C standard. See it like a sidekick, as Robin for Batman.)

That's some awful code for sure but actually not hard to decipher. Just find out which is the inner-most expression (as per operator precedence) and untangle it from there. The "compound assignment" operators might be helpful here:
var1  = (adc_T>>3) - ((BME280_S32_t)dig_T1<<1);
var1 *= (BME280_S32_t)dig_T2;
var1 >>= 11;

type tmp = (adc_T>>4) – (BME280_S32_t)dig_T1;
var2  = tmp * tmp;
var2 >>= 12;
var2 *= (BME280_S32_t)dig_T3;
var2 >>= 14;

This could probably also have been made readable by starting with creating a bunch of temporary variables of type BME280_S32_t after which the casts wouldn't be necessary.
However there is very likely 5 or so bugs in there, which happens whenever someone decides to write code like this...
For example if these are direct accesses to volatile qualified registers, reading the same register over and over in sequence is wrong. Having multiple unsequenced volatile accesses in the same expression even leads to undefined behavior.
And did they truly consider implicit integer promotion in each and everyone of these subexpressions? (We can't tell because all type info in missing)

I would convert to more lines and introduce additional variables. Any optimizing compiler will not create them.
IMO the best tool to split those horrible expressions automatically is ChatGPT which for example can convert your expression into:
BME280_S32_t adc_T_shifted3 = adc_T >> 3;
BME280_S32_t dig_T1_shifted1 = (BME280_S32_t)dig_T1 << 1;

BME280_S32_t var1 = (adc_T_shifted3 - dig_T1_shifted1) * ((BME280_S32_t)dig_T2);
var1 = var1 >> 11;

BME280_S32_t adc_T_shifted4 = adc_T >> 4;
BME280_S32_t diff_T1 = adc_T_shifted4 - (BME280_S32_t)dig_T1;

BME280_S32_t var2 = (diff_T1 * diff_T1) >> 12;
var2 = (var2 * (BME280_S32_t)dig_T3) >> 14;

BME280_S32_t t_fine = var1 + var2;

BME280_S32_t T = (t_fine * 5 + 128) >> 8;

It can also generate nice doxygen comment:
// Shift raw ADC temperature reading right by 3 bits to reduce precision for intermediate calculations.
// This is part of the scaling required to align the raw ADC value with the calibration constants.
BME280_S32_t adc_T_shifted3 = adc_T >> 3;

// Shift calibration parameter dig_T1 left by 1 bit to double its value.
// This effectively multiplies dig_T1 by 2, which is required for the temperature compensation algorithm.
BME280_S32_t dig_T1_shifted1 = (BME280_S32_t)dig_T1 << 1;

// Calculate var1 as the product of the adjusted temperature difference and calibration parameter dig_T2.
// The result is then shifted right by 11 bits to scale down the value and fit it within the expected range of var1.
// The shift right helps to avoid potential overflows and matches the scaling in the compensation formula.
BME280_S32_t var1 = (adc_T_shifted3 - dig_T1_shifted1) * ((BME280_S32_t)dig_T2);
var1 = var1 >> 11;

// Shift the raw ADC temperature reading right by 4 bits for a different level of precision.
// This shifted value is used in further calculations to compensate for non-linearities.
BME280_S32_t adc_T_shifted4 = adc_T >> 4;

// Calculate the difference between the shifted adc_T value and dig_T1.
// This difference is used to determine the quadratic term in the temperature compensation formula.
BME280_S32_t diff_T1 = adc_T_shifted4 - (BME280_S32_t)dig_T1;

// Calculate var2 by squaring diff_T1 to account for non-linear temperature effects, then shifting right by 12 bits.
// The shift helps reduce the range to avoid overflow and maintain a suitable precision for further calculations.
// Multiply by calibration parameter dig_T3, and then shift right by 14 bits to scale the value appropriately for var2.
BME280_S32_t var2 = (diff_T1 * diff_T1) >> 12;
var2 = (var2 * (BME280_S32_t)dig_T3) >> 14;

// Calculate t_fine as the sum of var1 and var2.
// t_fine is an intermediate variable used for fine-tuning the temperature calculation and is also used in pressure compensation.
BME280_S32_t t_fine = var1 + var2;

// Calculate the final temperature value by multiplying t_fine by 5, adding 128 for rounding purposes, and then shifting right by 8 bits.
// The shift right by 8 bits ensures the final temperature value is scaled correctly (in degrees Celsius, multiplied by 100).
BME280_S32_t T = (t_fine * 5 + 128) >> 8;

PS I know that AI answers are not allowed but it answers the OP question. clang-format is not "smart" enough for that and I just want to show him the correct tool

Can clang-format do this automatically (probably not)? If they were willing to reformat manually they wouldn't need clang-format.

@Barmar I forgot one sentence :)

@Barmar clang-format does have a similar option in v20 for splitting up operators (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#breakbinaryoperations), but doesn't handle parentheses. In the end, this is not the only datasheet I have to read, and I would prefer an automated clang-format solution for the future. So, no, since this isn't an automated solution that uses clang-format, I don't believe it answers my question.

I'd say that wall of text explaining basic arithmetic as if I'm 7 years old is as bad as the original...

@Lundin all automatic tools are like this. Thats exactly what OP wanted

Just for the record, this kind of AI usage on site is allowed. The AI output posted is merely an example of how AI processed input data looks like and the rest of the answer does not have any AI generated content. Now whether it is really prudent to use AI for such task, considering that output might get incorrectly modified during processing is completely different story.
